# Save a copy of Database then email it to a shared email box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a script that saves a backup database (with a date stamp) to a shared drive.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim fs As Object Dim oldPath As String, newPath As String 
    Dim CurrentDate As String

    CurrentDate = Format(Now, "MMDDYY")
    oldPath = "\\xxx\xxx Database" 'Folder file is located in 
    'newPath = "\\xxx\xxx\FINANCE\USERS\xxx\xxx Operations\xxx\xxx\" 'Folder to copy file to 
    newPath = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx\xxx" 'Folder to copy file to

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    fs.CopyFile oldPath & "\" & "xxx Database Update v.1.6_be.accdb", newPath & "\" _
    & "xxx Database Update v.1.6_be_" & CurrentDate & ".accdb"

    Set fs = Nothing

    MsgBox "Database Backed up", , "Backup Complete" 

End Sub
```

This worked fine.

However I have now been asked to also send the database to a shared inbox email address.

```
Private Sub btnbrowse_click()

    Dim filediag As FileDialog
    Dim file As Variant

    Set filediag = FileDialog(msofiledialogfilepicker)

    filediag.allowmultiselect = False
    If filediag.show Then
        For Each file In filediag.selecteditems
        Me.txtattachment = file
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSend_Click()

    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    oEmail.To = Me.txtto
    oEmail.Subject = Me.txtsubject
    oEmail.Body = Me.txtbody
    If Len(Me.txtattachment) > 0 Then
        oEmail.Attachments.Add Me.txtattachment.Value
    End If
    With oEmail
        If Not IsNull(.To) And Not IsNull(.Subject) And Not IsNull(.Body) Then
            .Send
            MsgBox "Email Sent!"
        Else
            MsgBox "Please fill out the required fields."
        End If
    End With       
End Sub
```

Please can somebody help me link the two scripts so that instead of using the FileDialog to choose the email attachment, I can use the path in the first query to select the attachment and the script will run both the save file and the email file commands at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It's just the filename, so it could be just passing the value from your script:

```
oEmail.Attachments.Add newPath & "\xxx Database Update v.1.6_be_" & CurrentDate & ".accdb"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just automatically send after the backup, make the email code a Sub that can be called in Backup button click procedure.

```
Sub SendEmail(strFile As String)
...
oEmail.Attachments.Add strFile
...
End Sub
```

Then calling the sub at end of the Backup button click:

`SendEmail(newPath & "\xxx Database Update v.1.6_be_" & CurrentDate & ".accdb")`

Many email systems reject emails with Access file as an attachment because of malicious code risk. However, a zipped Access file should pass security. Example code:

```
Dim strZip As String
strZip = CurrentProject.Path & "\Construction.zip"
'create empty zip folder
'found this on web, no idea what the Print line does but if it isn't there, this won't work
Open strZip For Output As #1
Print #1, "PK" & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
Close #1
'copy file into zip folder
Dim objApp As Object
Set objApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'variable for source file doesn't seem to work in this line
'also double parens not in original example code but won't work without
objApp.NameSpace((strZip)).CopyHere CurrentProject.Path & "\Construction.accdb"
```

As noted in code comment, issue is passing source file via variable. Sorry, I never needed to solve.

Creating zip file code could be in the email procedure and then attach the zip file:

`oEmail.Attachments.Add strZip`

Then at the end of email procedure, can delete the zip file:
`Kill strZip`